# Java(open 11) Cassandra Client : connection refused

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have following java code to connect to cassandra:

```java
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

public class DBConnect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to cassandra connect");
PlainTextAuthProvider authProvider = new PlainTextAuthProvider("cassandra", "cassandra");
        String serverIp = "graph";
        String keyspace = "datastorage";
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoints(serverIp)
                .withPort(9042)
.withAuthProvider(authProvider)
                .build();
        Session session = cluster.connect(keyspace);
        System.out.println("Done");
        session.close();
        cluster.close();    
    }
}
```

I am using following dependencies:

```xml
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
      <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
      <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
      <artifactId>cassandra-driver-extras</artifactId>
      <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-unit</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.2.0</version>
</dependency>      
  </dependencies>
```

I get connection refused error : Caused by:

```log
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: graph/xx.xx.xx.xx:9042
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:225) ~[netty-transport-4.0.56.Final.jar:4.0.56.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291) ~[netty-transport-4.0.56.Final.jar:4.0.56.Final]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    ... 11 common frames omitted
16:50:21.744 [main] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - Shutting down
```

Need inputs on what I would be missing in my java spring project configuration.

Comment: Most probably you are hitting the wrong port. Please check if port  is correct

Comment: I don't see a username or a password specified.  Although, that would yield a different error message.  Might not want to show the IP here if it's not secured.

Comment: Thanks for response, I tried adding PlainTextAuthProvider (Updated code in Question) but that didnt help. Still stuck with same error. Any inputs would be valuable.

Comment: Is "graph" defined in your hosts file?

Comment: Yes, i tried by defining graph in host file, but that didnt help. And error that i am still getting is io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: graph/xx.xx.xx.xx:9042.